# What is the purpose of the tf.contrib module in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm curious about what `tf.contrib` is, and why the code would be included in TensorFlow, but not in the main repository.

Furthermore, looking at the example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py) (from the tensorflow master branch), and I want to find the source for `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket`.

It seems like some cool routines, but I wanted to make sure they were properly using queues, etc, for pre-fetching/pre-processing examples to actually use them in a production setting.

It appears to be documented [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#TensorFlowClassifier), but it is from the [tflearn](https://github.com/tflearn) project, but `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket` doesn't seem to be in that repository either.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In general, `tf.contrib` contains *contrib*uted code. It is meant to contain features and contributions that eventually should get merged into core TensorFlow, but whose interfaces may still change, or which require some testing to see whether they can find broader acceptance.

The code in `tf.contrib` isn't supported by the Tensorflow team. It is included in the hope that it is helpful, but it might change or be removed at any time; there are no guarantees.

The source of `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket` can be found at

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column.py#L365

Comment: contrib stands for CONTRIButions

Comment: I believe it is important to point out that `tf.contrib` has been removed from Tensorflow starting with version 2.0.alpha. Some of the functionalities in the old `tf.contrib` package have been moved to tensorflow/addons, but not all of those. For anyone in need of porting an old _contrib_ feature to TF 2.0, you might find some useful info [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md).

Comment: Hey, tf.contrib is removed from TF 2.0 onwards. How do we contrib to tensorflow in that case?