# what is the difference between tf.nn.max_pool() and tf.layers.max_pooling2d()

Tags: tensorflow

I am a beginner of tensorflow,i have met two methods about create max_pool layer these days. one is "tf.nn.max_pool()" and the other is "tf.layers.max_pooling2d()".i want to learn about its difference,and when to use them suitably.based on this ,i have read its official document and searched in google,it is not any help at all.i have searched it in stackoverflow , there is a similar answer([tf.nn.conv2d vs tf.layers.conv2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785026/tf-nn-conv2d-vs-tf-layers-conv2d)）but it didn't solve my problem.does any one can help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow - Why are there so many similar or even duplicate functions in tf.nn and tf.layers / tf.losses / tf.contrib.layers etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172725/tensorflow-why-are-there-so-many-similar-or-even-duplicate-functions-in-tf-nn)