# Why `xavier_initializer()` and `glorot_uniform_initializer()` are duplicated to some extent?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, initializer

`xavier_initializer(uniform=True, seed=None, dtype=tf.float32)` and `glorot_uniform_initializer(seed=None, dtype=tf.float32)` refer to the same person Xavier Glorot. Why not consolidate them into one function?

`xavier_initializer` is in `tf.contrib.layers`. `glorot_uniform_initializer` in `tf`. Will the namespace of `contrib` eventually go away and things in `contrib` will be moved to the namespace of `tf`?

Comment: For the benefit of posterity, please consider accepting whichever answer helped you the most!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer` and `tf.glorot_uniform_initializer` both implement the same concept described in this [JMLR paper: `Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks`](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf), which can be seen in the code:

- [tf.glorot_uniform_initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L1210)
- [tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L31)

With typical values for `fan_in`, `fan_out`, `mode = FAN_AVG` , and `uniform = True`, both implementations sample values from the *standard uniform distribution* over the limit **[**`-sqrt(3), sqrt(3)`**)**

Because [`tf.initializer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py) has support for a wide variety of initialization strategies, it's highly likely that it will stay whereas the initialization from contrib which just has `xavier_initialization` will most probably be deprecated in future versions.

So, yes it's highly likely that in future versions the `tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initialier` way of initialization might go away.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question! I'll start with `tf.contrib`:

Will the namespace of `contrib` go away? Only when there's no more unstable community contributions to add to TensorFlow - so never. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060825/tensorflow-what-is-tf-contrib-and-where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-tf-con) may be of interest. I'll summarize. 
The `contrib` namespace is for user-contributed code that is supported by the community (not TensorFlow). Code in `contrib` is useful enough to be in the API, and probably will be merged eventually. But, until it's thoroughly tested by the TensorFlow team it stays in `contrib`. I'm *confident* the docs used to explain why `contrib` exists, but I can't find it anymore. The closest thing is in [the API stability promise](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/version_compat), which explains that **`contrib` functions/classes are subject to change!**

A little more in-depth, things in `contrib` generally merge into `tf` eventually. For example, the entirety of `Keras` merged from `contrib` to `tf.keras` in 1.4. But, the exact process of the merge varies. For instance, compare `tf.contrib.rnn` and RNN functionality in `tf.nn`. Quite a bit of `tf.nn` aliases `tf.contrib.rnn`. I mean, click *anything* on the [`tf.nn.rnn_cell` guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/rnn_cell). You'll be looking at the `tf.rnn.contrib` doc! Try it! It seems that using `tf.contrib.rnn` is very stable, despite the fact that it's migrated into "native" `tf`.  On the other hand, the `Datasets` merge isn't so clean (`contrib`'ed in 1.3, merged in 1.4). Because some - very few - bits of code were changed during the merge, using `tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset` will give you a nice depreciation warning. And, some things have been in `contrib` for quite a while and show no signs of merging soon: [`tf.contrib.training.stratified_sample`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/training/stratified_sample) comes to mind. I believe `contrib.keras` had been around for a while before merging.

Now onto Xavier/Glorot:

Here's links to the source for [`contrib.xavier...`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L56) and [`tf.glorot...`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L582). The source code looks (nearly) the same, but let's follow `variance_scaling_initializer`. Now things differ: `xavier` has [a function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L62) and `glorot` uses [a class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/python/ops/init_ops.py#L378) (`VarianceScaling` is aliased as `variance_scaling_initializer`). Similar again, yes, but at a glance the "native" `tf` version gives us some different error messages and some better input validation.

So why not remove `contrib.xavier`? I don't know. If I had to speculate, it's because `contrib.xavier` took off. I mean, I still use it and I still see it all the time (citation needed?). Now that I know `glorot` is basically the same, I'm not sure that I'll *keep* using `contrib.xavier`. But I digress. I suspect `xavier` has stayed around because removing it would break a reasonable amount of code. Sure, there's no stability promise for `contrib`, but why fix (or break) what's not broken?

Posting an issue or pull request on Github could generate some more interesting responses from actual contributors. I suspect you would get reasons it hasn't and won't be removed, but maybe not. My quick search for "xavier" and then "glorot" in the Issues suggests it hasn't been asked before.

**EDIT:** To be clear, as kmario points out, they're mathematically identical. I'm pointing out that the implementation, as it is today, differs slightly in the realm of input validation and structure. He seems to think xavier is more likely to depreciate than I initially thought. I'll happily defer to him because he's probably more experienced than I am.

Comment: Great answer.  Thanks.